# How to send emails using smtp.gmail.com with oauth access token for service account?

Tags: asp.net-core, smtp

I know that smtp.gmail.com will no longer support less secure apps in 2021. In order to migrate to using oauth access tokens, I am trying to understand the flow.

I do not want to access users gmail account information, I simply want to send them an email that contains password recovery link for my application. Everything I've been reading talks about getting access_token and displaying consent screen to the user before sending emails. This indicates to me that all these tutorials assume you want to send emails on behalf of the user.

I just want to use a single gmail account to send password recovery emails. How can this be achieved?

Comment: You may be confusing things. You'd need a secure app to do something on behalf of another user, and for that you need the oauth token and such. But it sounds like you only want to send email, from your account, to the other user's account. For that you don't need them to grant you any privileges. You just make sure your program can send as you, and you're good to go.

Comment: Yeah that is exactly what I want to do. But looking online all the blogs begin with "Go to your google account and enable Less Secure apps" but google will be deprecating that support in 2021, so I thought you would be forced to use oauth for simple email sending.

Comment: If that was the case, no user of e.g., yahoo.com or whatever could send email to gmail users.

Comment: https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2020/03/less-secure-app-turn-off-suspended.html?m=1